# Time complexity of getting max value from Min Priority Queue backed by a Heap

Tags: java, max, heap

I ran into a question online asking for the **average** time complexity of getting the maximum value from a Min Priority Queue backed by a Heap.

I reasoned the answer to be `O(n)` because a heap is backed by an array, and iterating through the array once to find the maximum would take `n` comparisons.

However, the answer is `O(nlogn)`. Can anyone explain why this is the case and where my reasoning fails?

Comment: You're correct, assuming the heap is given to you preconstructed.  Whoever told you it's n log n is wrong.

Comment: @LouisWasserman What if I were to implement the Heap with pointers like a normal binary tree? Could you then traverse it in linear time?

Comment: Yes.  Doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A heap **can** be backed by an array (if you choose to implement it that way). As most programming languages have arrays, it makes sense to do so. But from the outside, we cannot assume that.

And yes, technically, you can find the max value in linear time **If you have access to the array**, which you will not. Example...in Java, do you have access to the dynamically sized array behind the ArrayList class? No, because Java does not want you to mess it up!

Assuming that you can only use the public methods / attributes exposed by the Heap class...You are more than likely not going to have access to that array. If that array were publicly available, it can be easily manipulated, and the Heap structure could be easily compromised.

I think the question assumes that you would use the Heap's methods. And in a min heap, the max value would come out at the end (heapsort), which would require `n` calls to the `remove()` function, which is `O(logn)`, so `n * log(n)` implies that the heapsort is `O(n*logn)`.

In short, the question is asking the time complexity of heap sort.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I kind of assumed we would have access to the backing array, but it makes sense why I wouldn't.